# Error En Consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy haciendo esta consulta en SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    RP.idRegistroP, 
    CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ', E.Apellido_Materno,' ', E.Apellido_Paterno) AS Empleado, 
    P.Nombre AS Concepto, 
    Rp.No_Pagos, 
    RP.Fecha_Entrega, 
    Count(DRP.Monto) AS Pagos_Realizados
FROM Registro_Percepciones AS RP
    INNER JOIN Empleados AS E ON E.idEmpleado = RP.Empleado
    INNER JOIN Percepciones AS P ON P.idPercepcion = RP.Percepcion
    INNER JOIN Detalle_RPercepciones AS DRP 
        ON DRP.id_RPercepciones = RP.idRegistroP
    GROUP BY RP.idRegistroP, 
    CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ', E.Apellido_Materno,' ', E.Apellido_Paterno), 
    P.Nombre, Rp.No_Pagos, RP.Fecha_Entrega, DRP.Monto
```

pero en cuanto agrego el campo `'COUNT(DRP.Monto) AS Pagos_Realizados`', ya no me muestra nada de datos, lo cual se me hace extraño, ya que tengo otra consulta igual, pero con otras tablas que si me muestran los datos sin problemas

Comment: estás diciendo que si quitas el count, te entrega datos?

Comment: si, pero se me hace raro, algo que acabo de recorda, es que la tabla 'Detalle_RPercepciones' la agregue despues de haber hecho las demas tablas, no se si eso tenga algo que ver

Comment: sorry, pero no me parece posible....si dejas tu query exactamente igual, pero quitas el count sí te entrega datos?, puedes revisar eso nuevamente?

Comment: si, asi si lo hace, lo deja de hacer cuando agrego la referencia para la tabla Detalle_RPercepciones y el campo count

Comment: ah, bueno, eso es diferente...la explicación es simplemente que no hay registros de la tabla Registro_Percepciones que hagan match con los datos de la tabla Detalle_RPercepciones. El count no tiene nada que ver

Comment: si, me acabo de dar cuenta, hay alguna manera de hacer que me muestre un 0?

Comment: Sí, cambia el `INNER JOIN` con la tabla `Detalle_RPercepciones` por un `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En los comentarios mencionaron uno de los errores de esa consulta, el cual es que si la tabla `Detalle_RPercepciones` no tiene datos, la consulta no generará resultados. Por lo tanto, un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (la palabra OUTER es opcional) es necesario para mantener los datos. Otro detalle que debes de cuidar es que las condiciones de los JOIN sean correctas.

Por último hay un error común entre los que no dominan SQL y es que incluyes la columna agrupada en las columnas del `GROUP BY`. Esto evitará que puedas agrupar la columnas y el `COUNT()` siempre regresará 0 (cuando no hay datos) o 1 (cuando sí los hay).

Al final, la consulta debería quedar así.

```
SELECT  RP.idRegistroP, 
        CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ', E.Apellido_Materno,' ',  E.Apellido_Paterno) AS Empleado, 
        P.Nombre AS Concepto, 
        Rp.No_Pagos, 
        RP.Fecha_Entrega, 
        Count(DRP.Monto) AS Pagos_Realizados
FROM Registro_Percepciones       AS RP
INNER JOIN Empleados             AS E   ON E.idEmpleado = RP.Empleado
INNER JOIN Percepciones          AS P   ON P.idPercepcion = RP.Percepcion
LEFT  JOIN Detalle_RPercepciones AS DRP ON DRP.id_RPercepciones = RP.idRegistroP
GROUP BY RP.idRegistroP, 
        E.Nombres,
        E.Apellido_Materno,
        E.Apellido_Paterno, 
        P.Nombre, 
        Rp.No_Pagos, 
        RP.Fecha_Entrega;
```